# How to override only ItemTemplate in Custom Control

Tags: wpf, themes, styles

I want to create a Custom Control derived from `ComboBox`, however if I create custom control from visual studio template, it creates a default `Style` of Control and I have to then open MSDN's `ControlTemplate` of `ComboBox` and then recreate the entire `ComboBox` style once again in a generic.xaml

What I want to do is, I want to create a custom control derived from `ComboBox` and in the generic.xaml I only want to define an `ItemTemplate` and not entire `ControlTemplate`.

However if I keep the line

```
static MyComboBox()
{
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.
         OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyComboBox), 
         new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
             typeof(MyComboBox)));
}
```

Then I dont see anything at all if I remove the `ControlTemplate` from generic.xaml, however if I define key `ItemTemplate` in generic.xaml, how should I initialize my static constructor in order to refelct only `ItemTemplate`?

Sure I can redesign the xaml theme from msdn help but isnt there any easy way to do it?

Comment: Have you tried doing a style that sets the control template? Something like <Style.Setters><Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource myItemTemplate}"></Style.Setters>

Comment: @Carlo, i do not want to set ControlTemplate, i only want to set ItemTemplate, if i set ControlTemplate then i will have to write everything what default combobox has already defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recently wrote my own custom combobox that only changes the ItemTemplate of the control. The rest of the combobox style is inherited from the default combobox.

In your custom control constructor:

```
 static CustomComboBox()
 {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomComboBox)
                        , new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomComboBox)));

 }
```

And then in your generic.xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomComboBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}">
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                **INSERT YOUR ITEM TEMPLATE HERE**
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The key here is setting the style's BasedOn property to reference the standard combobox control.

Hope this helps!